# how to get informations about operations rest api on azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, operation, azure-management-api

i tried to get all operations (Get, Put, Delete)etc.. on a specific storage account but I don't get all information (on which container, on which blob)..

I tried these two api :
1)

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/XXX/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?metricnames=Transactions&timespan=2022-12-18T02:00:00Z/2022-12-20T02:05:00Z&\$filter=apiname+eq+'*'+and+ResponseType+eq+'*'+&interval=PT24H&aggregation=Total&orderby=Total+desc&api-version=2019-07-01
```

but I get only the number and the response type

2)
https://management.azure.com//providers/Microsoft.Storage/providers/operations?api-version=2019-07-01

Comment: Are you tryying to operate with storage account control layer or data layer? What is the the actual information you are trying to fetch?

Comment: hello I am trying to get list of the transactions on the storage account with details : (type of api, date, response type, on which container this transactions )etc..

Answer (score 0):

Data layer operations are available on resource log(diagnostics logs).

Refer documentation how to enable logging into log analytics workspace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage?tabs=azure-portal#collection-and-routing

After turning on logging you can run queries to fetch operation from `StorageBlobLogs` table.

Comment: I enabled the logging but I can't find StorageBlobLogs table in  my analytics workspace, how can I add it ?

Comment: Tables are created automatically when logs are being ingested.

Answer (score -1):

*Use the below params as headers to get rid of un- authorization error while accessing the API*

x-ms-date :
x-ms-version :
Authorization : SharedKey storagename: Signature

*Authorization is shown in below snippet*

[image]
[image]

[image]

*Create a storage account and container in Azure*

*Storage account*

[image]

*Container*

[image]

code in C# to fetch the Headers of  x-ms-date ,
x-ms-version , and Authorization

```
 using (var Req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri)
            { Content = (requestPayload == null) ? null : new ByteArrayContent(requestPayload) })
            {

                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                Req.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("2022-12-26 8:40:16 PM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                Req.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2022-09-01");
                Req.Headers.Authorization = AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper.GetAuthorizationHeader(
                   storageAccountName, storageAccountKey, now, Req);

                using (HttpResponseMessage Resp = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(Req, cancellationToken))
                {
                    if (Resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        String xmlString = await Resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        XElement x = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
                        foreach (XElement container in x.Element("Containers").Elements("Container"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Container name = {0}", container.Element("Name").Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

for more information, please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-rest-api-auth#download-the-sample-application)